# How to wrap 'leaflet-geosearch' in 'react-leaflet' application?

Tags: react-leaflet

I want to warp 'leaflet-geosearch' to work in a react.js application that uses leaflet-geosearch. Is this possible?

Any examples of this would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a [custom react-leaflet component](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html#docsNav) to do this.